# Question on derivative

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

I have this :

[image]
And i don't understand (3.5) .

i.e : why $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt} G_t(\eta(t)u)=(G'_t(\eta),\eta ')+\partial_tG_t(\eta))$

Please
Thank you .

Comment: I would guess that it's some kind of functional chain rule, but I don't quite see it.  Look in the rest of the book/article to see if they use a similar device with possibly more explanation.

Comment: there is not more